# How to make (correctly) runtime database connection in python telegram bot?

Tags: python, postgresql, database-connection, telegram-bot, peewee

I'm doing my first telegram-bot-project using python+peewee+postgresql (without django).

I just want to know, how to connect to my database not once (in the start of my project's code), but everytime when it's needed. For example: *user tap on button -> connection opens -> it adds line to table(s)*

---

Right now file structure looks like this:

*tgbot.py*

```
# some lines with imports

updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp = setup_dispatcher(dp)

# some lines with logging config

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

*dispatcher.py*

```
# some lines with imports

# some def for event handlers
# !!!!! here will be database connections (in functions for events)

def setup_dispatcher(dp):
    db_conn = DBConnection()  # Enter database connection
    from dbmodels import db
    db = db_conn.get_connection()

    ToDo.create(...)  # creating line in postgres-table

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start)) 
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('location', ask_for_location))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.location, change_location)) 
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('today', ask_for_today))

    return dp
```

*dbhelper.py*

```
# some lines with imports

class DBConnection(Singleton):

    def __init__(self): ...  # initializing some variables like self.database, etc

    def get_connection(self):
        """ Creating PostgreSQL's database connection """
        if self.connection is None:
            try:
                self.connection = PostgresqlDatabase(self.database, user=self.user, password=self.password, host=self.host, port=self.port)
                self.curs = self.connection.cursor()
            except (Exception, Error) as error:
                print("PostgreSQL's connection error: \n", error)
                sys.exit(1)
        return self.connection

    def __del__(self):
        """ Closing database connection """
        if self.connection is not None:
            self.curs.close()
            self.connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL's connection closed.")
```

*dbmodels.py*

```
# some lines with imports

db = PostgresqlDatabase(None)

class Singleton:
    """ Singleton realisation for database connection class in dbhelper.py """
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

class BaseModel(Model):
    """ Basic class, used for tables-classes in models.py """
    class Meta:
        database = db
```

*models.py*

```
# some lines with imports

class User(BaseModel):
    """ A model for client's table """
    # initializing some fields
    class Meta:
        db_table = "clients"
    ...

class ToDo(BaseModel):
    """ A model of to-do's table """
    # initializing some fields
    class Meta:
        db_table = "to_do_s"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all completely unnecessary. The peewee database object is already a singleton. You just need to call the `connect()` and `close()` methods on it when you want to connect/close.

Alternatively you can use the database instance as a context-manager, e.g.:

```
db = PostgresqlDatabase(...)
with db:
    ToDo.create(...)
```